# Can't get Eclipse to work under Windows 7 64 Bit

Tags: eclipse, windows-7

Currently I'm trying to run Eclipse Classic under Windows 7 x64, without success.

First, I've downloaded the JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-jsp-136632.html).
Second, I've downloaded the Eclipse 32 bit Version, which crashes while showing the splashscreen, for a very short time.

The 64 bit version at last, shows an error message, that the `jvm.dll can't be loaded` (shown path is valid).

What can I do now? Java seems to work, as I can run Netbeans and other Java Applications.
I also have no error log of Eclipse, as no workspace is setup.

Comment: Okay, no it is starting to get really strange! Removed JDK 64 Bit, isntalled 32 Bit and now I'm getting the exact same error on Eclipse 32 Bit, that it fails to load the jvm.dll!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it! For both, 32 & 64 Bit version. I used the posted Eclipse.ini setting from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659),  edited the paths to fit my environment and bam! It worked. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running a **64 bit JDK**, that `JAVA_HOME` is set properly, and that `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is in the front of your *path*. 
I also might try running eclipse from the `DOS` prompt to see if you get any startup error info there.